# PHP: form action on same page, still show same until refresh

Tags: php, caching, forms

Yes, Im having a little edit profile page, `index.php?mode=profile`. Lets take the username in the editprofile form as example. The username is already in the username-field. So i changed from "Peter" to "Tom" and press save.

The action is `?mode=profile&edit=true`. So now when i have pressed save it has updated the column in the db from Peter to Tom. But this field keeps having the value "Peter" until if i do press refresh (or f5), then "Tom" will appear. Like it hasnt updated in the database anything, although it did but it still shows Peter until next refresh.. like it caches, but it shouldnt cache nothing?

Any help on this? Is it because its on the same "page" / file? what can i do

Comment: a small code snippet would help

Answer (score 0):

I think you fetch the data first, put it in the form and then update the database contents. You should update the database contents first when  you submit the form. The fetch and creation of the form should be the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're rendering the page before doing any of the profile modifications. Make sure you're dealing with changes to the profile before you render it (i.e., all your database calls to update values should be before the SELECT statements to render the page).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in each input field of your form just echo post values for respective fields.

For eg -

lets take an example of username field -

```
<input type="text" name="username" value='<?php echo $_POST['username']?>' />
```

By this way if you post any field then that value will be displayed and not from cache.

In my above example i haven't cleaned the post data, make sure that you use cleaned post data
in actual scenario.

Comment: Bad idea, especially as you haven't cleaned that data before displaying it.

Comment: @fredley: i assumed that the cleaning part is standard and will be done by @Karem. anyways modified my solution with that note.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP provides two methods : POST and GET. With URL starting with ?param= you are actually using GET. "GET" should be used if and only if the form processing is idempotent query (ie the page content is NOT altered by the query).

If your form modifies data, you should use POST method.